# Automatically generate a stacked bar chart with Dynamic Ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am looking to develop a tool for my coworkers to use that automatically generates a stacked bar chart.  I need this to work for any sized data set, for any number of `Product` and any number of `Part`.  So, I need an auto-adjusting VBA range for my macro, and I'm not sure how to do it.

It needs to do the following:

- Takes the SUM of values in a row, and logs it at the column on the end.
- Creates a stacked bar chart for each of the rows.
- Go to "Select Data" and "Switch Rows and Columns"
- Turns the `Total` data values to `No Fill`
- Makes the `Total` data labels show up "Inside Base"
- removes the white space from the stacked bar chart by changing the maximum of the Y-Axis.

My problems are the following:

- The recording of the Macro didn't record setting the `Total` data selection to No Fill.  How should I do this for just the `Total` data points?
- How do I use VBA to switch the rows and columns?
- And then finally, I am not sure how to make this macro work for any sized data set?

Here is a sample data set that I have been practicing on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19n_UH2fJxomur13G_I89WRaqW93KH6Z0FIpUOzsciyE/edit#gid=0

Here is the type of chart that I want to create:
[image]

And here is the macro that was created when I did it manually:

```
    Sub StackedBar1()
'
' StackedBar1 Macro
'

'
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
    Range("G3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
    Range("G4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
    Range("A1:G4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet3'!$A$1:$G$4")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionInsideBase
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 14
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 8
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If you use the time spent making this post in analyzing and improving your recorded code, you would have discovered how it works and should've come up with a possible solution to your problem. What you're asking doesn't show specific problem though so honestly, I don't know where to start if I were to answer this. Try narrowing down your problem first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I happen to agree with you now.  In VBA, I would like to only select the `Total` column and then format it with `No Fill`?

Comment: Nevermind - I did this: `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Total").Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try the dynamic, but it should look something like that:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long

'Define last column and last row in datasheet
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'define range    
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Name").Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(lastRow,lastColumn))
```

To set a lable and make it transparent:

```
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelInsideBase)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(lastColumn-1).Fill.Visible = msoFalse
```

Switching Rows/Columns, depending on your need:

```
ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns
'Or
ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens!  How would I set the Maximum Scale of the "Total" column + 2.  Right now, I have: `With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
    .MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("Total"))+2
    End With` and I am having some trouble.

Comment: I don't know what your "Columns("Total")" reference is doing. Rather refer with absolute values like this: `ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns(lastColumn)) + 2`